# VBA - Replace a word with a condition

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a code to replace certain words with its corresponding values in a word doc. which is working well.
But, I'm held up in one scenario for which I need assistance.

I have one particular word in my document called "DATE" which has to be either replaced by "StartDate" or "EndDate". 
Here, I need a code which should read the whole word document.
**If it finds a word called "End",** the word "DATE" must be replaced with "EndDate".
Else, by default, the "DATE" can be replaced with "StartDate" itself.

```
With WDoc.Content.Find .Text = "End" 
 If (.Text = "End") Then .Text = "DATE" 
  .Replacement.Text = "EndDate" 
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue 
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 
 End If 
 .Execute FindText:=Key, ReplaceWith:=Dict(Key) 
End With
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you show us the code that you have written thus far. That way it would be easier to propose a solution.

Comment: With WDoc.Content.Find
         .Text = "End"
         
                  
         If (.Text = "End") Then
         .Text = "DATE"
         .Replacement.Text = "EndDate"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If
        
            .Execute FindText:=Key, ReplaceWith:=Dict(Key)
        End With

Comment: This is replacing the DATE with EndDate without searching the document, though END is not present in the document. :(

Answer (score 3):

The Script below will search the ActiveDocument for the word "End" matching the case, if the case doesnt matter then change `MatchCase = False`.
If "End" is found then the `.Text` changes to "Date" and is replaced with "EndDate".

I'm not sure about your line `.Execute FindText:=Key, ReplaceWith:=Dict(Key)`

```
Sub FindFindAgainAndReplace()

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = "End"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute

        If .Found = True Then

            .Text = "Date"
            .Replacement.Text = "EndDate"
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

         End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @sweety just remember to up vote and mark answers you found to answer your question. Enjoy StackOverFlow!